# workflow for multiple related feature branches

Tags: git

Assume I need to work on two features: `FEATURE1` and `FEATURE2`. `FEATURE2` is related and should be developed on top of `FEATURE1`.

I created `FEATURE1` from `MASTER`. Usually the best scenario is to finish off `FEATURE1`, merge back to `MASTER`, and only then branch `FEATURE2` directly from `MASTER`.

There are some limitations in this case, however:

- `FEATURE1` is almost done, but cannot be merged to `MASTER` straight away.
- The work of `FEATURE2` should start where `FEATURE1` left off.
- `FEATURE1` and `FEATURE2` should be merged back to `MASTER` *separately* (they should be tested/verified *separately*).
- It's likely that there would be some additional changes on `FEATURE1` before it can be merged to `MASTER` (**after** the work on `FEATURE2` has started).

So for this case the questions are:

- Whether branching `FEATURE2` from `FEATURE1` (as done in the diagram) is a good choice?
- What should be done to minimise possible conflicts when merging `FEATURE1` and `FEATURE2` (separately) back to `MASTER`?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd branch `feature2` based on whatever your current state of `feature1` is.

Once you developed a new API in `feature1` (case 1) or `feature1` is ready for production and has been merged into `master` (case 2), you should rebase `feature2` on either `feature1` (case 1) or `master` (case 2).

Case 1, `Q` is the new API or correction:

```
master   A B C D
          \
feature1   M N P Q
                  \
feature2           X' Y' Z'
```

Case 2, `M` is the merge commit of `feature1` and `master`:

```
master   A B C D M
          \     / \
feature1   M N P   \
                    \
feature2             X' Y' Z'
```

Comment: Because feature2 and feature1 need to be merged separately, I suppose your `case2` is what I need to do then.

Comment: Both cases are something that I encountered in my daily git practice. Case 1 is for getting `feature1` functionality into `feature2` (i.e. pretending `feature2` was started later in time after `Q` was done), case 2 is to pretend `feature2` was started after `feature1` was fully merged into `master`.

Answer (score 1):

Branching from `FEATURE1` is the correct choice, and there shouldn't be too much trouble with that.

Assuming `FEATURE1` development will continue after branching into `FEATURE2`, you can merge the two separately and git will handle it just fine.

Of course, if both `FEATURE1` and `FEATURE2` operate on the same lines of the same files, you will have merge conflicts as per usual, and you'll need to resolve them before continuing with your merge. If they do not touch the same lines, however, you aren't expected to have any merge conflicts, and are free to merge them both at your leisure.

If `FEATURE1` branch will not have any further commits after FEATURE2 was branched, and `FEATURE2` is merged back into master, you will not be able to separately merge `FEATURE1` (as `FEATURE2` already included all of the commits in `FEATURE1`).